# How can I create a log in and sign up form in on modal also when I submit it the modal stay?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a modal that contains login form and the register form. I want to hide the registration first so that the log in form is the one they will see first, then when they click the registration `label` on the top the form will change in to my registration form. I had a code that worked however when I refresh the page and open the `modal` the both log in and register is displayed together. How can I hide the registration form and also how to submit the form that the `modal` will still open when reloaded?

Here is what I am talking about

[image]

```js
$(".lgn").on('click', function() {
   $("#login-form").fadeIn();
   $("#registration-form").fadeOut();
});
$(".rgs").on('click', function() {
   $("#registration-form").fadeIn();
   $("#login-form").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 4; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal-header {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.con-logreg {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.con-logreg .registration {
  display: none;
}
.modal-header .toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: center-modal;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes center-modal {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal p {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.modal a {
  color: #4f6ed1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  float: right;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form {
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}
.form-control {
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 10px; /* Some padding */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  resize: vertical; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.form-control-signup {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 10px; /* Some padding */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  resize: vertical; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}

form .submit {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0f66c9;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.submit:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #032f61;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.submit-signup {
  background-color: #0f66c9;
  width: 85%;
  height: 5%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto 70px;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.submit-signup:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #032f61;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <div class="desc">
    <div class="tooltiplgn">Ratings is highly appreciated</div>     
    <button class="login"   type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Loginmodal"><span><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></span>Feedback</button>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="Loginmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <a class="toggle lgn" id="active" href="#login-form" data-box="login-form">Login</a>
        <a class="toggle rgs" href="#registration-form">Registration</a>
     
        </div>

    <div class="con-logreg">
    <div id="login-form" class="registration">
    <form action="" id="contact-form" method="post">

    <b><p>Email</p></b>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/Email" required>

    <b><p>Password</p></b>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <p>Don't have account yet? <a href="Signup.php">Signup</a></p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control submit">
    </div>
</form>
    <div id="registration-form" class="login-form">
                       
    <form action="Includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your full  name" required>
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your valid username" required>
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your valid Email" required>
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter a strong password" required>
                    <p>Re-enter password</p>
                    <input type="password" name="pwdrepeat" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Re-enter password" required>
                    <button class="submit-signup" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            
            </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <div id="registration-form" class="login-form"> does this class the right one ? I can't find the class .registration in ur html ?!

Comment: I'm sorry I've change it the same as loginform let me update it. My apology,

Comment: I've already edited the code thank you

Comment: Load the jquery script at the start of the snippet plz and chk out the load statement <script src=...

Comment: I don't know why it is not working on snippet but in my code it is. Is there another way rather than js?

Comment: I already updated the code the snippet now working thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try my snippet i have edited yours, sorry was having to much work so wasn't able to answer through mob, anyway i hope that's what exactly u need

```js
$(".lgn").on('click', function() {
   $("#login-form").fadeIn();
   $("login-form").css('display', 'block');
   $("#registration-form").fadeOut();
   $("#registration-form").css('display', 'none');
});
$(".rgs").on('click', function() {
   $("#registration-form").fadeIn();
   $("#registration-form").css('display', 'block');
   $("#login-form").fadeOut();
   $("#login-form").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 4; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  bottom: -10;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
.modal-header {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.con-logreg {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.con-logreg .login {
  display: none;
}
.con-logreg .registration {
  display: none;
}
.modal-header .toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: center-modal;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes center-modal {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal p {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.modal a {
  color: #4f6ed1;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
  float: right;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form {
  transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
}
.form-control {
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 10px; /* Some padding */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  resize: vertical; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.form-control-signup {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 10px; /* Some padding */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure that padding and width stays in place */
  resize: vertical; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 15px;
}

form .submit {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0f66c9;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.submit:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #032f61;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.submit-signup {
  background-color: #0f66c9;
  width: 85%;
  height: 5%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto 70px;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.submit-signup:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  background-color: #032f61;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <div class="desc">
    <div class="tooltiplgn">Ratings is highly appreciated</div>     
    <button class="login"   type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Loginmodal"><span><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></span>Feedback</button>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </div>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="Loginmodal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <a class="toggle lgn" id="active" href="#login-form" data-box="login-form">Login</a>
        <a class="toggle rgs" href="#registration-form">Registration</a>
     
        </div>

    <div class="con-logreg">
    <div id="login-form" class="login">
    <form action="" id="contact-form" method="post">

    <b><p>Email</p></b>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username/Email" required>

    <b><p>Password</p></b>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <p>Don't have account yet? <a href="Signup.php">Signup</a></p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control submit">
    </div>
</form>
    <div id="registration-form" class="registration">
                       
    <form action="Includes/signup.inc.php" method="post">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your full  name" required>
                    <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your valid username" required>
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter your valid Email" required>
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Enter a strong password" required>
                    <p>Re-enter password</p>
                    <input type="password" name="pwdrepeat" class="form-control-signup" placeholder="Re-enter password" required>
                    <button class="submit-signup" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            
            </div>
  </div>
        </div>
    
      </div>
      
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```